# How to boot into recovery mode without cmd-r?

Tags: macos, recovery

I am trying to boot into recovery mode on a Mac Pro with 10.11.1.

I have a firmware password set. When I boot into the boot menu (alt key), I can click on the password textfield and type the password and click on the round button next to it to proceed to the boot menu.

However, when I try to boot into recovery mode with cmd-r, the mouse doesn't react and, why?, the password textfield doesn't have focus. I cannot type the password.

How can I boot into recovery mode without being confronted with this dilemma?

Comment: Would holding the Option key at startup and selecting the Recovery partition from there work?

Comment: It only shows one partition.

Comment: At least post the output from these commands: `diskutil list`, `diskutil cs list` and `sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk0`.